# If statement not executing some part of the code

Tags: c#, asp.net

When on dropdownlist1 item 1 is selected, on the dropdownlist2 the items that star with "02" and "03" should be disabled, and when on dropdownlist1 item 2 is selected on the dropdownlist2 the items that start with a "01" and "03" should be disabled

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "01")
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "02") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = false);
    }
    else
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "02") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = true);

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "02")
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "01") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = false);
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "01") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = true);
        }
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "01")
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "02") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = false);
    }
    else
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "02") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = true);

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "02")
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "01") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = false);
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "01") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = true);
        }
    }
}
```

The on page load is working as intended the items on dropdownlist2 are correct showed but as soon as I change the item on dropdownlist1 to item2 and again to item1 the dropdownlist2 does not show anything at all, but the item2 on dropdownlist1 is working normally.

Comment: This would be a great time to learn to use the debugger!  Set a breakpoint, step through to see what the problem is (i.e. is the logic wrong? is there something wrong with your code? etc.)

Comment: The ItemChanged Event is going to be called by the Load Event.  You may want to register the Change Event at the end of the Load Event instead of in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Greg said, you should learn to debug.

#### Here's what you're doing..

You got a List of items in your 2nd ListBox:

```
01, 02, 03
```

Step 1 - Select `01` in ListBox1: Deactivate `02` and `03`

```
ListBox2.Items = { 01 }
```

Step 2 - Select `03` in ListBox1: Activate `02` and `03`, Deactivate `01` and `03`

```
ListBox2.Items = { 02 }
```

Step 3 - Select `01` in ListBox1: Deactivate `02` and `03`

```
ListBox2.Items = { }
```

Result: *You forgot to activate everything at the beginning.*

#### Easier Solution

Set the `Enabled` everytime for every element. This way you don't have to bother about the status before changing.. And it's shorter..

```cs
protected void DropDownList1_ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == x.Value.Substring(0, 2)));
}
```